# Umbraco on save and publishing showing error

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to Save and publish code on Admin side in:

```
Content>Home page>recipies>Ingrediantname >Some comment
```

But on clicking save and publish its showing error as shown in image

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Its asking for some Permission and i had set hi as administrator also in usertype I have provided the rights of publishing by click that checkbox

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking this up in the log file? It's located in App_Data/Logs

Comment: @Mark please see my log detail and also I have some related issue on link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409421/on-submit-click-getting-issue-in-umbraco

i assume that this issue are related to each other