# On submit click getting issue in umbraco

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008-r2, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6

I have one submit click on which the comment get submitted for particular product or thing but on clicking that I am not able to submit that commnet and facing issue as seen in below images
[image]

[image]

Another thing is that this things are working properly in my local host but when I upload it on my beta/staging/Live server I am facing this issue.
I have also tried deleting umbraco.config file and log file but still facing same issue

Also on log file I can see the issue as

[image]

I have one issue for what i assume both issue are interlink to each other
[Umbraco on save and publishing showing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282645/umbraco-on-save-and-publishing-showing-error)

My controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using umbraco;
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;
using xyz.Controls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace xyz.Controllers
{
  public class CommentsController : UmbracoApiController
  {


  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason this issue is tagged with sql-server-2008-r2 but the error message you're receiving is a MySql error?

Comment: I am not using Mysql any where I am using sql server 2008-r2 but as i reviewed for issue "Access Denied for USER " " (using password NO),
this issue i seem for my sql

Comment: @Mark do I need to make some changes on my Staging/Beta Dtabase side?

Comment: I have same controller file on my local side and is working fine, Actually this is umbraco and using such structure it stores value in an XML format, this all is working fine on my local but issue is on Staging/Beta side

Comment: Can you post the implementation of the GetComment method and especially the piece where Umbraco hits the database?

Comment: @Mark There is no method named GetComment written in over all application still on local it is working and on beta side it is not working, I think the CommentsController which inherit UmbracoApiController is working on its own and storing data in umbraco.config file in xml format

Comment: @Mark I dont know from where umbraco calls the database but we had set the connection string manually on webconfig as NOTworking string : " <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="server=somename;database=databasename;user id=mff;password=mff" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />" | working string :   <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="server=somename;database=databasename;user id=sa;password=EDGE#2015" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved while going in to Machine.Config of sql server and updating the syntax as

```
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="LocalMySqlServer"/>
<add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="Datasource=localhost;Database=users;uid=root;pwd=password;"
   providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the logs you are showing are error logs so it does not look like your code is logging the 500 error.

from what I can see, you have a method GetComment on the CommentsController that is failing server side. If you don't have a try catch wrapping the code in that method then you need to add that and log the error.

```
try
{
...Your method code here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
LogHelper.Error(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType, ex.Message, ex);
}
```

Upload your changes to the server and then run the page with the error.  Hopefully you'll have an error message in the current log file in app_data/logs/

Comment: Well there is no method named GetComment  in CommentsController , please review my updated question where i m placing my controller code

Comment: I have same controller file on my local side and is working fine, Actually this is umbraco and using such structure it stores value in an XML format, this all is working fine on my local but issue is on Staging/Beta side

Comment: Some part of you code calling GetComment method somewhere which is throwing an error.  Maybe you installed a package perhaps? Anyway, have you tried republishing the entire website on live.  Also was this working before?

Comment: There is no method named GetComment written in over all application still on local it is working and on beta side it is not working, I think the CommentsController which inherit UmbracoApiController is working on its own and storing data in umbraco.config file in xml format